# Equivalent of numpy.dot (python) in Fortran

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, fortran

I have code in python that I need to "translate" to Fortran (that I don't know that much....)

I have :

```
>>>Mat1
array([[ 0.2],
       [ 0.4],
       [-0.2],
       [-0.8]])
>>> X
array([[0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Then I do :

```
Result=np.dot(X,Mat1)
```

I would like to do the equivalent in Fortran

```
REAL(8), DIMENSION(4,1)::Mat1
REAL(8), DIMENSION(4,4)::X

X(:, 1)=(/0, 0, 1, 1/)
X(:, 2)=(/0, 1, 1, 0/)
X(:, 3)=(/1, 0, 1, 0/)
X(:, 4)=(/1, 1, 1, 1/)

Mat1(:,1)=(/0.2,0.4,-0.2,-0.8/)
```

But in this case `numpy.dot` is not really doing a dot product... I don't know if I should use `DOT_PRODUCT` or `MATMUL`. Things are really unclear for me.

Comment: real(8) is really ugly and non-portable.

Comment: I'm not used that much in fortran, what should be the best way ? why ? Thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, MATMUL is the way you want to go. See [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/fortran/Vector_and_matrix_multiplication.htm). DOT_PRODUCT is only for vectors. MATMUL can handle any matrices whose dimensions allow matrix multiplication.

In your example, your matrices don't have matching dimensions. Math (not just FORTRAN) expects an `m*k` matrix to be multiplied by a `k*n` matrix. You need to swap the axes of Mat1.

**EDIT**: Or, as francescalus notes, you can make it a rank-1 vector by declaring `DIMENSION(4)`.

Comment: I have tried but I get `The shapes of the arguments are inconsistent or nonconformable` ....

Comment: Yeah, you can't multiply a 4x1 by a 4x4. That's math rules, not just FORTRAN. You need to transpose the 4x1 into a 1x4.

Comment: Or you can change how you declare and assign to it, swapping the axes.